# Proper handling of Controls on a WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I got a ComboBox with five entries and five UserControls.

When I choose the ComboBox Entry one, I want to assign the first UserControl to my grid.
On the second ComboBox entry, the second UserControl, on the third entry... and so on.

Now each UserControl contains a bunch of Controls, such as TextControls, ComboBoxes and CheckBoxes.

Let's imagine the following pseudocode:

```
combobox_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
    if(comboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
       grid.Content = new UserControlOne();
    else if(comboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
       grid.Content = new UserControlTwo();
    else if(comboBox.SelectedIndex == 3)
       grid.Content = new UserControlThree();
    [...]
}
```

On a Button Click, I want to get the Values of the assigned control, but I don't know how to access the UserControl.

```
buttonSave_click()
{
    //TODO: Get Values of a UserControl and assign it to the Model-Class    
}
```

How do I access the Controls of the UserControl and get their values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would do something like this using the MVVM design pattern

The `ComboBox` would be bound to a collection of `ViewModel` or `Model` objects

So you'd have

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"
          DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" />
```

where `SomeCollection` is a collection of `object` on your `ViewModel`, and `SelectedViewModel` is an `object` property to hold the selected item

```
SomeCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
SomeCollection.Add(new ViewModelA());
SomeCollection.Add(new ViewModelB());
SomeCollection.Add(new ViewModelC());
SomeCollection.Add(new ViewModelD());
SomeCollection.Add(new ViewModelE());

SelectedViewModel = SomeCollection[0];
```

Now your `SaveCommand` can access whatever is selected by using `SelectedViewModel` and casting it into the appropriate type based on `typeof(SelectedViewModel`)

Personally I would use a generic interface like `IViewModel` instead of an `object`, and have it contain some generic properties (such as `DisplayName`) and methods. Depending on your functionality, you could even have it contain it's own save logic, so you could execute this in the save command:

```
SelectedViewModel.Save();
```

As for displaying the correct View/UserControl, I would use a `ContentControl`, with it's `Content` bound to your `SelectedViewModel`, and use implicit data templates to tell WPF how to draw each object

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
            <local:UserControlA />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
            <local:UserControlB />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelC}">
            <local:UserControlC />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelD}">
            <local:UserControlD />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelE}">
            <local:UserControlE />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: *That* was a *very* nice job. Cheers

Comment: It was indeed, I am grateful for that. Sadly I can't simply move the entire application to the MVVM pattern :(

Answer (score 1):

Add dependency properties to the `UserControl`'s class and bind them to the properties of the controls inside the `UserControl` which you wish to expose to the world. This allows your `UserControl` to present a suitable interface to the outside world, while doing whatever it needs to do in the safety of its internal environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please provide a sample for me? I've never worked with dependency properties before as I'm fairly new to WPF.

Comment: A sample probably won't help you understand it - I suggest you find some good WPF UserControl walkthrough and documentation and read it carefully. There's a lot of information about it online.